# How to run a command recursively for files with specific extensions in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to run a command from root folder recursively which will affect all files under that root folder with a specific extension.

Here is the command

```
blender b03.blend --background --python myScript.py
```

Instead of b03.blend file I want to run this command for every file with .blend extension.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at GNU `find` and its action `-exec command ;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```sh
find . -name '*.blend' -exec blender {} --background --python myScript.py \;
```

Explanation:

- `find` any file that matches `*.blend` - use of single quotes is important so that your shell doesn't expand this for any files in the current directory
- then for each file found, execute `blender {} --background --python myScript.py`. The `{}` is replaced with the file's name, for example `some/sub/tree/file.blend`.
- `\;` will terminate the `-exec` statement. The `\` is used to escape the `;`, so that the shell doesn't absorb it and split the line into multiple commands.
- All instances of `blender` will be run from the initial working directory, so `blender` must be able to correctly handle a file that is not 'here', and equally access the `myScript.py` that is not a neighbour of the `*.blend` file(s).

*NOTE*: I'm not familiar with `blend`, but if it will go into the background and take some time to process (due to `--background`), then you may overwhelm your machine... You might prefer to process one file at a time, or perhaps break the job into a handful of independent jobs that can run serially (each item to completion)... for bonus points look at something like `make` that can easily run concurrent operations while working with restrictions (e.g: `make -j 8` will run at most `8` commands at once).